# Issue with Discrete Double Fourier Series in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft, curve-fitting, least-squares

The formula for the discrete double Fourier series that I'm attempting to code in MATLAB is:

[image]

The coefficient in front of the trigonometric sum (Fourier amplitude) is what I'm trying to extract from the fitting of the data through the double Fourier series seen above. Using my current code, the original function is not reconstructed, therefore my coefficients cannot be correct. I'm not certain if this is of any significance or insight, but the second term for the A coefficients (Akn(1))) is 13 orders of magnitude larger than any other coefficient.

Any suggestions, modifications, or comments about my program would be greatly appreciated.

```
%data = csvread('digitized_plot_data.csv',1);
%xdata = data(:,1);
%ydata = data(:,2);
%x0 = xdata(1);
lambda = 20; %km
tau = 20; %s
vs = 7.6; %k/s (velocity of CHAMP satellite) 
L = 4; %S 

% Number of terms to use:
N = 100;

% set up matrices:
M = zeros(length(xdata),1+2*N);
M(:,1) = 1;
for k=1:N
    for n=1:N %error using *, inner matrix dimensions must agree...
        M(:,2*n) = cos(2*pi/lambda*k*vs*xdata).*cos(2*pi/tau*n*xdata);
        M(:,2*n+1) = sin(2*pi/lambda*k*vs*xdata).*sin(2*pi/tau*n*xdata);
    end
end

C = M\ydata;

%least squares coefficients:
A0 = C(1);
Akn = C(2:2:end);
Bkn = C(3:2:end);

% reconstruct original function values (verification check):
y = A0;
for k=1:length(Akn)
    y = y + Akn(k)*cos(2*pi/lambda*k*vs*xdata).*cos(2*pi/tau*n*xdata) + Bkn(k)*sin(2*pi/lambda*k*vs*xdata).*sin(2*pi/tau*n*xdata);
end


% plotting
hold on
plot(xdata,ydata,'ko')
plot(xdata,yk,'b--')
legend('Data','Least Squares','location','northeast')
xlabel('Centered Time Event [s]'); ylabel('J[\muA/m^2]'); title('Single FAC Event (50 Hz)')
```

Comment: so the problem is because the inner matrix dimensions don't agree :)  you probably want .*

Comment: @thang Yep. It was as simple as that...

Comment: always good to have another pair of eyes instead of scratching your head for a long time...